# Documenting Java EE components in Ant script

Tags: java, ant

I'd like to document Java EE components that we create. Our ant scripts have targets to build them all.  I was wondering if there is anything like "javadoc" for an ant script.  In other words, I could annotate the ant targets:

```
<target name="some.war'>
  <antdoc>
      This war file provides the user interface for the foo application.
  </antdoc>
...
</target
```

Does this even seem like a good idea? Maybe I'm better off creating a regular document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant has a description tag:

```
 <target name="some.war">
    <description>
           This war file provides ...
    </description>
  </target>
```

I think that is as good as it gets. I think it is a good idea and use it all the time. Most tasks have description attribute as well, which is good for short descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

At the build script level, you could use the `description` attribute of a [`<target>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#targets):

```
<target name="some.war" 
 description"This war file provides the user interface for the foo application.">
...
</target>
```

But, more important, be sure these details are provided in the `<description>` element of the `web.xml` of a WAR and/or the `application.xml` of an EAR.